# margin is not working as it should work

Tags: html, css

I wanted to achieve like this

```
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|           |                |                |
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```

but got like this

```
+-----------+----------------+
|           |                |
+-----------+----------------+----------------+
                             |                |
                             +----------------+
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bFqTv/1/)**

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/bFqTv/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you need to change the order of the elements:

```
<div class="wrap cf">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="two">two</div> <!-- put the element without class right to the end -->
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bFqTv/30/

Comment: Oh! Thanks. That was I doing previously but unknown about this issue that order is must.

Answer (score 4):

Use following CSS if you don't want to increase the width:

```
.wrap cf{width: 500px; background: red; position: relative;}
.one{width: 200px; float: left; background: blue;}
.three{width: 200px; background: blue;float:left;}
.two{width:200px;float:left;background:red;}
```

Comment: floating all to left, that I know but I'm so serious about margin is not working as my previous works.

Comment: @Chapurlink In this case all three divs have 200px width and you can also change the width as you want. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the `width` in `.wrap` , I increased it to `800` and all are in one line

Comment: I need without increasing the width.

Comment: Previously I was doing like mine and was working properly but couldn't find what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrapper of 500px, and try to fit three (3) boxes in it of 200px? That just can't work... Enlarge your wrapper until it fits the sum of all the boxes you want to have in it. Or make your boxes smaller...

Oh, and make sure you enlarge your window enough to show the full xxx pixels...

Comment: I need (2) box only 100px then?

Comment: You only need 2 boxes? Then, if you need to have your wrapper at 500px, you can set each of your boxes to 250px - the margin (if you add a margin to a box, that is a perimeter OUTSIDE of the size of it, so you need to add it to the overall size that is used.

Comment: Not only 2 boxes. I mean for box (2) if it is only 100px and (1) and (3) are 200px then, it should work but what is missing so it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is keep those DIVs (one, two and three) in a row, they all need to fit within 500px like this:

```
.wrap{width: 500px; background: red; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
.one{width: 200px; float: left; background: blue;}
.three{width: 100px; float: left; background: blue;}
.two{width: 200px; float: left; background: red;}
```

Also note that I've given  width for every DIV

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
.wrap{width: 500px;overflow:hidden; background: red; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
.one{width: 200px; float: left; background: blue;}
.three{width: 200px; float: left; background: blue;}
.two{width: 100px; float: left;}
```

NB clear the float properly rather than just `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

- The div with class '.two' (which is the middle of the 3 boxes) is a block element without any given float of left or right, therefore it will clear and
  take up the remaining space of the first line.
- And also, the margins you've added to '.two' aren;t required.
- Finally you forgot the '.cf' (code for clearfix) in the css.

Here is a possible solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/bFqTv/28/

```
.wrap{width: 500px; background: red; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
.one{width: 200px; float: left; background: blue;}
.three{width: 200px; float: left; background: blue;}
.two{ width:100px; float:left;}

/**Source:http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/**/
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}


/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do two things:

1. Float all inner elements left with `float: left;`
2. Give all innerelements a width: `width: 33%`

Updated CSS:

```
.wrap{
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.one, .two, .three {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.one, .three {
  background-color: blue;
}
.two{
  background-color: red;
}
```

You HTML:

```
<div class="wrap cf">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bFqTv/29/

Answer (score 0):

In you first class name in HTML is **wrap cf** but you are using only **wrap** in your CSS.I think you need to set your 3 div inside 500px width.Use CSS like i mentioned

```
.wrap cf{width: 500px; background: red; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
.one{width: 200px; background: blue;float: left}
.three{width: 100px; background: green; float: left}
.two{width: 200px;  background: red; float: left }
```

This CSS works well on my side.Hope it works on your side as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap{width: 500px; background: red; position: relative; margin: 0 auto}
.one{width: 100px; float: left; background: blue;}
.three{width: 100px; float: left; background: blue;}
.two{width:100px; float: left;}
```

If require background red for second div use below

```
.wrap{width: 500px; background: red; position: relative; margin: 0 auto}
.one{width: 100px; float: left; background: blue;}
.three{width: 100px; float: left; background: blue;}
.two{width:100px; float: left; background: red;}
```

Thanks